# Is there any way of installing Ubuntu on Chromebook without using Crouton?

Tags: software-installation, chromebook

I have installed Ubuntu using Crouton and this is the only way I have found. But I would like to have a 100% Ubuntu computer so I can upgrade it with no problems. Has anybody have a link or something where I can find this information?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it is not possible to install it without Crouton, due to the way the Chromebook firmware is setup, etc. However with Ubuntu coming out with Unity 8 and more and more support for ARM architectures it may be possible, just hang in there! :)